# What is this lump with a brownish spot on my fishes head and how do I treat it?

Tags: fish, diseases

This spot has been on my fishes head for a couple of weeks.   It doesn't seem to be growing or changing.   Does anyone know what it is and how to treat it?[image]

Comment: a lot of information is missing from your question,type of fish,tank size,filtration,heating,a watertest PH-NITRITE-AMMONIA and information about how you cycled the tank before introducing fish to the tank.

Comment: this picture is obviously not a picture of your fish as it has been posted by an other user before.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AquariumHelp/s/HqCO2AHvzH